# mysql connections going too high vs queries running

Tags: mysql, apache, laravel, digital-ocean, galera

mysql connections going too high vs queries, using laravel 4 at application level with separate DB server for insert and read connections, with galera cluster.Servers are from Digital Ocean.

Answer (score 0):

That are not so much infos. Some things I would check:
 - how does the client (the client library) handle SQL connections?
 - is there any firewall in between that avoids a successful termination of client connections?
 - check `show processlist` or information_schema.processlist for running / hanging queries

This would be a good start.

Comment: Already used show processlist, there are all normal queries average of 1000 queries/s  <img src='http://www.system.dineordertest.com/public/uploads/server_monitor.jpeg'  width="200" height="200">

Comment: Already used show processlist, there are all normal queries average of 1000 queries/s   ![Server Monitoring](http://www.system.dineordertest.com/public/uploads/server_monitor.jpeg).  In given image link purple line is queries whereas blue one are connections,  sometimes number of connections goes much high and none of the queries work.

Comment: Hard to say. My first guess would be a locking query that runs for a long time and causes new queries to be rejected / run into a timeout. Did you enable the slow query log? The log files should tell you if you run into any system limits.

Comment: `SHOW PROCESSLIST` is a mysql command; it will _not_ include `<img...>`.